# Is it possible to run an R script on a layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, r, sextante-qgis-plugin

I'd like to run an R script on a layer loaded in QGIS (to rotate a set of points created there using the Vector:Research Tools:Regular Points tool). I thought ManageR might work but cannot get it working on OSX ...

Of course, I could do it manually (create layer -> run script from within R -> find output and reload into QGIS) but surely there is a more elegant solution?

Comment: On OsX you will need the python rpy2 package (to run ManageR). The QGIS OsX packager said yesterday that it will add it to his downloads page. Check the QGIS/OsX download page in the next days.

Comment: Nice - that will save a LOT of trouble! `easy_install rpy2` worked for me, and my paths seem correct, but manageR still seems to fail with `File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.2.2dev_20110903-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py", line 7, in 
    R_HOME = tmp.readlines()
IOError: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to get manageR working on OSX (Lion 10.7.2) at least.

It looks like the problem with manageR / rpy2 was actually problems with the previous R builds (2.13 at least) - symlinks were referring to the [wrong location](https://bitbucket.org/lgautier/rpy2/issue/78/truncated-path-to-librblasdylib-on-os-x).

1. Update R to 2.14 ([binary from r-project.org](http://www.r-project.org/));
2. Reinstall QGIS ([Kyngchaos installer](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis));
3. Reinstall GDAL_complete ([Kyngchaos again](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks));
4. Reinstall rpy2 (latter via [pip](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2_download.html)), rebooted ...

... and manageR now loads and works. Haven't tried this in Linux yet.

UPDATE:
The SEXTANTE plugin can be used to write scripts that call R, with [some modifications in OSX](http://press.underdiverwaterman.com/qgis-with-r-working-with-the-sextante-plugin/) to make it work properly.

Answer (score 6):

Currently I can't get manageR working on a Linux box - there's a problem importing layers into R from Qgis. I had a chat to Carson Farmer (the one-man magic machine who wrote manageR) and he's aware of the problem and is going to take a look at it sometime.

If that's your manageR problem (you weren't specific - couldn't get it working or couldn't get it installed? A problem getting Rpy2 on Mac?) then you'll just have to wait for that fix, or dive into the python and fix it yourself.

Otherwise, if the layer is saved as a shapefile or other OGR/GDAL source you'll have to get it via rgdal:readOGR or maptools:readShapeSpatial from R. Not too inelegant, but the other option is writing a bunch of python code to dump the layer to something like that yourself - which is essentially what manageR is all about...

Comment: ManageR fails to load ... at all ... giving errors that don't get fixed by any of the usual path fixes. rpy2 is installed just fine! I was hoping to avoid the 'write a bunch of python code' bit but that is starting to look like the best solution! Need to dive into it I guess (seems a bit less frightening now that I've worked out some R code).