# Need a spatial database that can be used by QGIS and R

Tags: qgis, r, spatial-database, database, ms-access

I'm quite new to QGIS and I'm searching  for a simple way to create a Database that allows me to use the tables in QGIS and R. I have a lot of data stored in Excel spreadsheets wich will be used for the statistical analysis in R.

My tasks in more detail:
My first task will be visiualizing the data by joining the tables to a shapefile.
Second I want to make some spatial transformations within QGIS with shapefiles and use the newly created data in my statistical analyse. Therefore I will have to join this data to my database.

Last but not least I wan't to assure that the data is stored in a good way for future analises in QGIS and R since the database will be used in other contexts.

Some tolled me that MS Access is a good way to do so. Can anyone of you give me some advice? Maybe on literature and stuff like that too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run an R script on a layer in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17169/is-it-possible-to-run-an-r-script-on-a-layer-in-qgis)

Comment: @R.K. I don't think it is duplicate, this question is about infrastructure creation, not about just running scripts.

Comment: I can understand the need for a DB Front end that allows you to control user input, GUI.  You'll definitely want to store the actual data in a spatially enabled DB, and potentially connect to it with Access if needed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Aside from Spatialite, you might also want to consider [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/). Think of it as Spatialite's big brother ;-) It's just another data source for QGIS while you can connect to it using the [RODBC](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html) package in [R](http://duncanjg.wordpress.com/2008/04/19/an-example-of-using-postgis-from-r/).

Comment: You can (probably) also get to PostGIS and Spatialite datasets in R using the rgdal package... I say probably because you just need the right drivers.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if you will be able to work with MS Access in QGIS (plus I haven't heard about any respectable GIS-project that would use MS databases); MSSQL - is supported (but never tried it myself and never will ;-) ).

Consider possibility to use [Spatialite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/) (spatial extension of SQLite). It will be quite suitable to operate Spatialite DB in QGIS and you can easily access Spatialite via R packages: [SQLiteMap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SQLiteMap/index.html); [RSQlite](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/index.html). This is the recipe I would use for myself.

**EDIT**: As was mentioned in comments (and I implied it), Spatialite require no server configuration, users administration, etc. And it is easily transportable to another computer by just coping database file.

Comment: +1 Don't use MS Access if you don't really have to.

Comment: all right. thanks for your repllies. I think i'll try out PostGIS!

Comment: +1 - Spatialite is a great option - QGIS reads both spatial and non-spatial tables directly, and the RSQLite package in R lets you read sqlite databases. 

Spatialite's great advantage is that you don't need to install and maintain a database - for all the advantages of PostGIS and MySQL, they need rather a lot of setup. The transportable, no-install nature of SQLite is convenient for your own use as well as sharing.

Comment: Spatialite = No server configuration!  You can copy your database and send it to someone without having to connect anyone to a server.